# API Call doesn't return

Tags: c#, asp.net

My .NET API has been acting really strange as of this afternoon. I have 1 call on my localhost API, which for some reason doesn't return anything, while it should actually 14 objects which should've returned. I have no clue where it could've gone wrong, especially since it did work earlier today, and I haven't changed anything in the process...

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<PreProgramRouteReturner>>> GetPreProgramRoute([FromQuery]string Key)
    {
        if(!(await KeyControl.Control(Key, _context))){
            return BadRequest("API Key bestaat niet");
        }
        List<PreProgramRouteReturner> returners = new List<PreProgramRouteReturner>();
        foreach(var item in _context.PreProgramRoute.Where(x => x.OrganisationKey == Key).Include(x => x.Weg).Include(x => x.Dagen)){
            var locatiereturner = new List<LocationName>();
            var home = await _context.LocationNames.Where(x => x.OrganisationKey == Key && x.Fractie == "HOME").SingleOrDefaultAsync();
            foreach(var item2 in item.Weg){
                locatiereturner.Add(item2);
            }
            var containers = item.Weg.Select(x => x.HoeveelContainers).Sum();
            
            List<string> dagens = new List<string>();
            foreach(var item3 in item.Dagen){
                dagens.Add(item3.Dag);
            }
            returners.Add( new PreProgramRouteReturner{
                Code=item.Code,
                Naam= item.Naam,
                Weg = locatiereturner,
                StartLocatie = home,
                EindLocatie = home,
                Inzamelgebiedtype = item.Inzamelgebiedtype,
                Containers= containers,
                xPerWeek = item.xPerWeek,
                InXWeken = item.InXWeken,
                dagen = dagens,
            });
        }

        return returners;
    }
```

The thing is, is that the API Call does work when i'm using a different Key (see parameters)

[image: Swagger showing it is continuously loading]

[image: VSCode debugging saying it has reached the end of the code]

Has it got to do with the fact that you cant return above a specific amount of objects, or has it got any other reason to do with it?

UPDATE: I've gotten an error, which might correspond to the error:

> status_breakpoint

Comment: _"Has it got to do with the fact that you cant return above a specific amount of objects"_ Nope, I'm not aware of any arbitrary limit.

Comment: That picture of VS Code looks like it's sat at a breakpoint and hasn't yet been allowed to continue and return the fetched data, which is why Swagger is still spinning because it's still waiting for a response.  Try removing the breakpoint and try again.

Comment: Looking again at the VS Code screenshot, `retruners` appears to contain 14 items!

Comment: The problem isn't the breaking point. I applied the breaking point so you can see returners should contain 14 items, yet it doesn't return anything